# Is There A Lost Focus Window Event in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Coming from a .NET background I'm used to events getting fired so trapping a lost focus event is easy but I'm not sure how to do this in Obj-C.  Basically I want my app to know when another application has gotten focus and it no longer has it so it can perform some actions.

Can you please tell me how I can implement this kind of functionality in Obj-C for an OSX app?

Comment: "Focus" is much more advanced/complicated on OS X than it is in .Net. There are several different types of "focus" and it's possible for multiple windows (and hundreds of objects) to all have focus at the same time. You're going to need to explain what you are trying to do in more detail to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the [`NSWindow`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html) notifications. Specifically, you're interested in `NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification` and `NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification`. You can also create a delegate for the window and implement its `windowDidBecomeKey:` and `windowDidResignKey:` methods, as noted in the [`NSWindowDelegate` protocol documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

Or, if you just wanted to know when the *application* (not a window) has gained focus, you can subscribe to the `NSApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. Likewise, `NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification` will notify you when your app loses focus. These notifications are discussed more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/index.html). You can also implement `applicationWillBecomeActive:` and `applicationWillResignActive:` in the [application delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

Comment: This will notify if a window loses focus.  It sounds like OP is looking for app losing focus.

Comment: @RupertPupkin: True, updated the answer to include that information.

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear if you want notification of a single window losing focus or notification of your entire app losing focus.  My answer here provides notification for the entire application losing focus.  (See mipadi's answer if you just want to know when one of your app's window loses focus.)

Observe the appropriate notification:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(appDeactivated:) 
    name:NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification 
    object:nil];
```

Then add the handler method:

```
-(void) appDeactivated:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSRunningApplication* app = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"NSWorkspaceApplicationKey"];

    if (app == [NSRunningApplication currentApplication]) {

        // your cleanup code here
    }
}
```